# Request for info about Real Analysis to a beginner

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, number-theory, education

So I'm a junior HS student very interested in mathematics and I think I have pretty good chances to get admitted into Stanford online HS and take a university level real analysis course that's worth 5 credits. It also says that a course on linear algebra and multi variable calculus is strongly recommended, but I have limited knowledge in those fields. What should I expect? What work should I do in order not to be overwhelmed and fail the course? Should I just switch to Elementary Number Theory?

Thanks in advance and sorry if that was too long :)

Comment: What will you treat in the course?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Topics: sequences, series, limits, continuity, differentiation, integration, and basic point-set topology. You can also check it out here :) https://onlinehighschool.stanford.edu/courses/2019/school-year/um115

Comment: You should do Stanford Online's course on linear algebra or multivariable calculus first!

Comment: Yes, do these first. Especially linear algebra. It will get you introduced to proof reading.

Comment: @Daron I’ve done some in my own country and by talking with the organizers they are checking the eligibility of them. I just wanted to know if it was going to be hard without having done their courses and what I should do to better prepare

Comment: U should do the linear algebra and multi variable calculus first, and then the real analisys one , for alot of reasons , one of them being is that for real analisys u need a bit of mathematical maturiaty with proofs and counterexamples, and every area of mathematics that you will encounter along the way in university will use linear algebra or calculus.

Answer (score 2):

**Do their recommended courses first.**

It is common to have Linear Algebra and Multivariate Calculus as prequisites to Real Analysis. In fact Linear Algebra and Multivariate Calculus are usually the first Pure Maths courses any university student takes.

So the two courses are taught with that *uninitiated* audience in mind, working not just as an introduction to the subject, but also an introduction to the differences between university level and high-school level maths. In particular university maths has a much higher degree of rigour and (if you're lucky) will focus more on understanding than on being able to tackle a prescribed list of problems.

Since this will be your first university level course, I suggest you follow the standard teaching order. It's true that Real Analysis won't require much *knowledge* from Linear Algebra or Multivariate Calculus. But you will find the level of rigour of Real Analysis very hard to swallow without a more gentle introduction the other two courses should offer.

I would be cautious about starting with Number Theory. Number theory deals with ideas you probably haven't seen in high school before, whereas the basic objects of Linear Algebra -- vectors and matrices -- and calculus -- derivatives and integrals -- should be more familiar to you. Also my Number Theory course was taught in second year and was more difficult because of that, so I wouldn't guess how Stanford's one fits into the framework.

My main advice to you is to not hurry the process.

Comment: Thank you! I might have been hurrying the process, but I have also done other work with university books and alike:
1. Matematika per Fakultetin e Ekonomise by Thoma Mitre, Omer Stringa and Bashkim Ruseti
This book focuses in two main parts: Linear Algebra (which includes mainly euclidian spaces, matrices, linear equations, Gauss' Method, Leontiev's Model) and Mathematical Analysis (which includes mainly the limit of a sequence, differential calculus, multivariable functions and integral calculus). The second part is still on progress and will end on June 18th.

Comment: 2. Algjebra Lineare dhe Gjeometria Analitike by Shkelqim Kuka and Adrian Naco
Has just been started. Focuses mainly on vectors, multidimensional plan, systems of equations, matrices etc.
3. Mathematik 2.1 and 2.2 Gymnasiale Oberstufe Hessen by Dr. Anton Bigalke and Dr. Norbert Köhler
Book used in high schools in Germany and learnt in school as part of my schools German department. Covers concepts of exponential functions, integral calculus, systems, vectors etc.
4. Matematika 11
Basic mathematics book used in Albanian high schools covering very basic concepts

Comment: Extra material as personal work:
1. Calculus: Basic Concepts for High Schoolers by L.V. Tarasov (in progress)
2. Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbot (not started yet)
3. Funksionet me shume ndryshore by Kujtim Baraliu (not started yet)
Paper that focuses on multivariable functions.